# How to call the webservice from Reactjs

Tags: javascript, http, reactjs

I am working on sample for which I am using Reactjs with webpack. How to call a webservice from reactjs components and pass the result to html file

I tried superagent, http-browserify etc 
All of them giving me same error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.

Below is the view component from where I am calling the API

```
import React from 'react'
import FindpersonStore from'../stores/FindPersonStore';
import PersonAPI from'../utils/PersonAPI';

var FindPerson = React.createClass({
    handleGoClick()
    {
        PersonAPI.getPerson(this.refs.personIdInput.getDOMNode().value);
    },

    render(){

         return(
        <div>
            <p>person Id <input type="number" value={this.props.personId} ref="personIdInput" /></p>    
            <input type="Submit" onClick={this.handleGoClick}/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
export default FindPerson
```

And The API is

```
import FindPersonAction from'../actions/FindPersonAction';
import {request} from 'superagent';

module.exports = {

  // Load mock product data from localStorage into ProductStore via Action
  getPerson: function(personId) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/SampleWebService/service/find?id="+personId

    request
        .get(url)//This is giving me error
        .end(function(res){
            if (res.status === 404) {
                        reject();
                    } else {
                         var data = JSON.parse(res);
                         FindPersonAction.findPerson(data);
                    }
        })

  }

};
```

Comment: What does your React code look like? This is a horrible and vague question.

Comment: Sorry.. I thought may be the modules that I used (superagent and http-browserify)  may not work with webpack and was looking at any other module suggestions to work with http and react. so I dint post code. anyways I updated the code. Please have a look at it

Comment: It's the way your import request. Just do `import request from 'superagent';` and you won't get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help its working now

Comment: But the response in res is null. When I watch the network using charles I am getting result. Please let me know what could be the problem

Comment: You're not parsing the text, do `JSON.parse(res.text)`.

Comment: Ok but  the 'res' itself is null  near function(res)

Comment: the result function has 3 arguments , where the 1st one is error and is null. so the request should be replaced with request
    .get(url)
    .end(function(err,res,res1){
     var data = JSON.parse(res.text);
    FindPersonAction.findPerson(data);
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function has the signature (err, res)
Change your code to that signature & change the import statement AS mentioned in the comments and it should work

Comment: BTW I think this is a poorly copied code. I cannot find where you should get the reject function. I don't see a promise and you are not importing it.

Comment: Forgot to mention that its working !!! yeah its working with  code Change that I metioned in above comment    -     request .get(url) .end(function(err,res,res1){ var data = JSON.parse(res.text); FindPersonAction.findPerson(data); }) and reject function is the function to handle error response.. which I dint mention in the above code..  Thanks for the support in resolving the confusion